# ERROR while trying to use Geany to commit messages

Tags: git, git-bash, geany

i was studing version control with git.

while trying to use geany to type commit messages, i got this error:

[Git Bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDxXq.png)

hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... **geany -imnst: geany: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'geany -imnst'**.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

necessary information:

- used git config --global core.editor "geany -imnst" for associating geany with git.

  https://wiki.geany.org/howtos/vcs_editor
- GeanyVC plugin is installed.

[GeanyVC plugin installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJuvS.png)

- I am able commit messages using geany manually (without using git bash, using geany only).

update: I added "C:\Program Files (x86)\Geany\bin" to the environment variable PATH and the error changed.

adding absolute path to core.editor didn't work.

new error: hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... Geany: Unknown option -imnst
error: There was a problem with the editor 'geany -imnst'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

[new error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfbOu.png)

UPDATE: SOLUTION IN COMMENTS.

Comment: First, make sure you have installed `geany`. If it's already been installed, you need either add its installation path to the environment variable `PATH`, or use its absolute path in the value of `core.editor`. Otherwise the system doesn't know where to find `geany` and invoke it.

Comment: i added "C:\Program Files (x86)\Geany\bin" to environment variable PATH. now the error changed.

Comment: Try `git config --global core.editor geany`. Remove the options and see if it works.